# Classwide variable with putExtra method?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, oncreate

I have a two activities of interest in my android app.:
Activity1 that goes to Activity2

I wish to pass some integer values to Activity2.

The Activity1 is like this:

```
    public class Activity1 extends AppCompatActivity {
// some code ...

//handle the click of a button
                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
                    intent1.putExtra("var1", 10);
                    intent1.putExtra("var2", 20);
                    startActivity(intent1);    
}
```

Then in Activity 2, I have this:

```
public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        int var1 = extras.getInt("var1");
        int var2 = extras.getInt("var2");
        int[] myIntArray = new int[var1*var2];

// more code...

}

// more code...

private OnClickListener myButtonListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        helperFunction1();
        return;
    }
};

private void helperFunction1(){
//need to access var1, var2 and myIntArray
}

}
```

Before I had a classwide variable for var1 and var2 so all methods in my Activity2 class could access them. But now, var1 and var2 have to be declared after onCreate is called in Activity2. I feel like there is a really easy solution, but how can I get var1 and var2 to act as classwide variables?

Thanks and sorry if this question is a bit complicated.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity{

private int var1 = 0;
private int var2 = 0; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        var1 = extras.getInt("var1");
        var2 = extras.getInt("var2");
        int[] myIntArray = new int[var1*var2];

// more code...
}
private void helperFunction1(){
int sum = var1 + var2;
}
}
```

Comment: Wow. I'm an idiot. I'll test it out tomorrow to make sure but I'm pretty sure it's right. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I understood that you want your var1 and var2  to be seen in all methods of the class. Simply, you need to do the following: 
1- declare private int before your onCreate method. 
2- assignment will be inside the oncreate method. So, whenever the class is called var1 and var2  have values from classA.

so your class should look like this :

```
public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity{
private int var1 ; 
private int var2 ;

// as well make myIntArray private 
private int[] myIntArray ; 
@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    var1 = extras.getInt("var1");
     var2 = extras.getInt("var2");
    myIntArray = new int[var1*var2];



}
```